# sed script interpretation: "0, /XXXX/! {0,/^XXXX/d}"

Tags: sed

Trying to interpret what the following script does:

```
sed -i "0,/ACCOUNT/! {0,/^ACCOUNT/d}" file.txt
```

My interpretation is that it is trying to delete header rows (the ones that have ACCOUNT as a headername) if found.  But running it on test files seems to be leaving the header rows intact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script deletes all lines from the line after the first line containing `ACCOUNT` up until and including a line starting with `ACCOUNT`.